# How do I make my urls work with mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm having rewrite issues.

http://test.bradp.com/drupal/Crocodile-Style/1 works OK.

http://test.bradp.com/drupal/Crocodile-Style/ DOES NOT WORK.

Apache throws a 404. The PHP logic defaults to page 1 without a page specified, so I know the script is fine.

Here's the code:
RewriteRule ^Crocodile-Style/([0-9]+)/?$ products/display.php?folder=crocodile-style&page=$1 [L,NC]

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the + modfier (1 or more) instead of the * modifier (0 or more).

Instead, you should use:

```
RewriteRule ^Crocodile-Style/([0-9]*)/?$ products/display.php?folder=crocodile-style&page=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up using two rules because it wouldn't work without the trailing slash.